# why the controller function isn't executing Angular Js 1.5.5

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-controller

I'm quite new to Angular js (4 hours of experiance) so I'll be straightforward :
i'm coding the basic examples of an online course, it was recorded in 2014.
The thing is that the function inside the controller is not executing, i know that i'm missing some very basic thing, but i searched for related questions here on StackOverflow and it didn't help, so I'm reling on.
here is the code snippets:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- the index.html file -->
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <title>Angular Udemy chap 2</title>
    <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div   ng-controlller="mainController">  
        <h1> Hello {{ name }} !!! </h1>
    </div> 
</body>
```

```
/* the app.js file */
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
myApp.controller('mainController',["$scope",function($scope){
$scope.name = "ElBarto";

}]);
```

Answer (score 3):

You misspelled `ng-controller` as `ng-controlller`. Fix the typo and everything should work.

Comment: thank's dude (i'm hitting my head against the wall )